# Spark-Java: Concatenate aggregated groupBy's result

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is what I am trying to do in Java but is not working as concat_ws requires Seq as the type of 2nd argument while collect_list return Column:

```
Dataset aggregatedDF = someDF
  .groupBy("colA")
  .agg(
      concat_ws(",", collect_list(col("colB"))).as("comma_sep_col_b")
  );
```

Same thing works in Scala:

```
val aggregatedDF = someDF
  .groupBy("colA")
  .agg(
      concat_ws(",", collect_list($"colB")) as "comma_sep_col_b"
  )
```

Comment: Works fine for me in java : Dataset aggregatedDF = df.groupBy("Age").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list(col("Wage"))).as("comma_sep_col_b"));
  aggregatedDF.show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`array_join()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#array_join) function.

**Background:**

The signature of `concat_ws` in Scala includes variable arguments

`def concat_ws(sep: String, exprs: Column*): Column`

Variable arguments of type `Column` in Scala are handled as `Seq[Column]`, with the Scala compiler providing the syntactic sugar management.

Note that the columns to be concatenated must be provided at *transformation time*, not execution time. `collect_list()` returns a single column, which is an `ArrayType(...)`.